# jQuery get random color from a given list

Tags: jquery, random

I would like to set a random color for the text of a fadeIn/Out text function I have

The functions (which works):

```
jQuery("div.custom_logo").ready(

    function(){

        //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
        var initialFadeIn = 1500;

        //interval between items (in milliseconds)
        var itemInterval = 2000;

        //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
        var fadeTime = 500;

        //count number of items
        var numberOfItems = jQuery("div.custom_logo").children().length;

        //set current item
        var currentItem = 0;

        //show first item
        jQuery("div.custom_logo").children().eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

        //loop through the items
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
            jQuery("div.custom_logo").children().eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                currentItem = 0;
            }else{
                currentItem++;
            }
            jQuery("div.custom_logo").children().eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        }, itemInterval);

    }

);
```

And Assuming I wanted colors:

blue: #37fff5
green: #8cff04
orange: #ffa018
hot pink: #f247f8

Although I know how I would add the color to the given element I do not know how could I choose a random color from the solors I have lsited above:

To change the color of the text that is fading in I would

```
//show first item
jQuery("div.custom_logo").children().eq(currentItem).css('color', theRandomColor).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);
```

AND

```
jQuery("div.custom_logo").children().eq(currentItem).css('color', **NEWRandomColor**).fadeIn(fadeTime);
```

Thank you,

Comment: Put the colors in an array and use Math.random to choose one. Here's a neat little article on getting whole numbers from Math.random http://www.shawnolson.net/a/789/make_javascript_mathrandom_useful.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this way is the best

```
RandomColor = function() {
    colors = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'green']
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
}
```

the return of the function will be the color
example:

a = RandomColor();
console.log(a) // "blue"

Answer (score 0):

```
RandomColor = function () {
    var _colors = ["#aaa", "#bbb", "#ccc", "red", "white"];
    this.getRandomColor = function() {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*_colors .length);
        return _colors[rnd];
    }
};

(new RandomColor()).getRandomColor();
```

Comment: Been writing Java recently or something? That could just as easily have been a simple function.

Comment: Simple fn :) ok: function a() { return ["#aaa", "#bbb", "#ccc", "red", "white"][parseInt(5*Math.random())] };