# Jquery - how to add different class/color to menu links

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu-list where I want each `<li>` of them to have a different background color when they are "active"

```
<ul>
  <li> // this <li> should have blue background when active
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li> // this <li> should have red background when active
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li> // this <li> should have yellow background when active
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li> // this <li> should have green background when active
    <a href="#">Link 4</a> 
  </li>
  <li> // this <li> should have orange background when active
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So, what would be my best approach to this?

Comment: Add a different class for each element in the list?

Comment: Have you tried any code at all? Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I haven't seen this before but there is a big misstake in your markup. you always open two `<li>` but you just close one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a quick code, that might help you understand how this works. You can use a class to trigger the active, or maybe you meant hover.. If you don't want the hover to go over the active, then change the location of hover above active, inside the CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #main_menu {list-style-type: none;} /* ul */
    #main_menu li {width: 100px; padding: 5px;}
    #main_menu li a {display: block; color: black; text-decoration: none;}

    /* Active static via the core program (PHP, CMS) */
    #main_menu li.active {background: black;}
    #main_menu li.active a {color: white;}

    /* Hover */
    #main_menu li:hover {background: blue;}
    #main_menu li:hover a {color: yellow;}

    /* Dynamic active */
    #main_menu li:active {background: green;}
    #main_menu li:active a {color: red;}
</style>
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#main_menu li a').click(function () {
        $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
        return false; // Kills the link action
    });
</script>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/82tDD/1/) ]**</sup>

Now that we know how does this system works. We can add your custom colors:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    #main_menu {list-style-type: none;} /* ul */
    #main_menu li {width: 100px; padding: 5px;}
    #main_menu li a {display: block; color: black; text-decoration: none;}

    /* Active */

    #main_menu li.first_item.active {background: blue;}
    #main_menu li.second_item.active {background: red;}
    #main_menu li.third_item.active {background: #FFFF00;}
    #main_menu li.fourth_item.active {background: green;}
</style>
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li class="first_item active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="second_item"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="third_item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="fourth_item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#main_menu li a').click(function () {
        $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
        return false; // Kills the link action
    });
</script>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/82tDD/2/) ]**</sup>

And I'm sensing, that you want them to be different color, because you have important links that are for different locations. So I added ID's version as well. So you can set under the ID different styles and then use them for the active statuses.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    #main_menu {list-style-type: none;} /* ul */
    #main_menu li {width: 100px; padding: 5px;}
    #main_menu li a {display: block; color: black; text-decoration: none;}

    /* Active */
    #main_menu li#home.active {background: blue;}
    #main_menu li#gallery.active {background: red;}
    #main_menu li#about.active {background: #FFFF00;}
    #main_menu li#contact.active {background: green;}
</style>
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li id="home" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id="gallery"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#main_menu li a').click(function () {
        $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
        return false; // Kills the link action
    });
</script>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/82tDD/3/) ]**</sup>

For the cross-browser problems, I wopuld not use the `nth-child(2)` method. However, what you could do, is that add `id=""` to those li items.. So in jquery you can use them better and from css you can pull the colors :)

Answer (score 0):

You can target your list via CSS. See a **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gcSbz/)**. Remember comments in HTML are `<!-- comment here -->`.

If you are not referring to the ::active pseudo selector, then you can change the CSS to show `ul > li* > .active { }` or `ul > li*.active > a`. You have a lot of options for selectors and styling elements on the page, but the idea here is that with CSS, you can target each `<li>` with the `:nth-child()` pseudo selector. Then, you don't have to load a library (jQuery for example) or wait for the small script to load and process (albeit vanilla JS is pretty slim).

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li> <!-- this <li> should have blue background when active -->
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li> <!-- this <li> should have red background when active -->
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li> <!-- this <li> should have yellow background when active -->
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
  <li> <!-- this <li> should have green background when active -->
    <a href="#">Link 4</a> 
  </li>
  <li> <!-- this <li> should have orange background when active -->
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul > li:first-child  > a:active { background-color: blue; }
ul > li:nth-child(2) > a:active { background-color: red; }
ul > li:nth-child(3) > a:active { background-color: yellow; }
ul > li:nth-child(4) > a:active { background-color: green; }
ul > li:last-child   > a:active { background-color: orange; }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/59cvc/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').on('click',function(){
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.active').css('background-color',RandomColor);
    });
});

RandomColor = function() {
    colors = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'green']
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
}
```

**Note:** I started with add Class active if you would like to handle the colors by css

part from random color was stolen here: [jQuery get random color from a given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089396/jquery-get-random-color-from-a-given-list) thanks to BernardoFire

Answer (score 0):

you might want to add an 'active' class to the list item.

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

in your css you could define a specific color for each :nth-child(n)

```
.active:nth-child(1){
     background-color: red;
}
.active:nth-child(2){
     background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following code :

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li> 
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
   ...
```

CSS

```
ul li:first-child.active {
    background-color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2).active {
    background-color: blue;
}

ul li:nth-child(3).active {
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul li:nth-child(4).active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('ul > li').click(function() { 
  $('ul > li').removeClass('active'); 
  $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/UWwR5/